# Conditionally evaluate an array element to return

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Considering the following data, I want to return the results of what id the **default** document to choose from within an Array field in MongoDB. Let's call the collection `books`. A sample collection data is shown below:

```
[
  {
     name: "Book1",
     refs: [{ oid: "object1" }, { oid: "object2" }, {oid: "object5", default: true }]
  },
  {
    name: "Book2",
    refs: [{ oid: "object3" }, { oid: "object5", default: true }, { oid: "object7" }]
 },
 {
    name: "Book3",
    refs: [{ oid: "object4" }, { oid: "object2" }]
 },
 {
   name: "Book4",
   refs: [{ oid: "object5" }, { oid: "object4", default: true } ]
 }
]
```

Okay. So a lot of the key values are in there for brevity but this doesn't change the point.

The desired logic here is as follows:

1. Find and return the document in the `refs` Array field that has a default of **true**
2. If there is no matching document in the array return the first document in the array

And following that logic, I would really like to see something returned as follows :

```
[
  {
    name: "Book1"
    refs: [{oid: "object5", default: true }]
  },
  {
    name: "Book2",
    refs: [{ oid: "object5", default: true }]
  },
  {
    name: "Book3",
    refs: [{ oid: "object4" }]
  },
  {
    name: "Book4",
    refs: [{ oid: "object4" }]
  }
]
```

Now I know there is the [$cond](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator in the aggregation pipeline, but part of this condition seems to be bound to getting a [$slice](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) on the projection where the `default` property does not exist on the document ( and is probably set to true but exists should suffice ).

This logic pattern rests on the expected results of using [$pull](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) to remove the element matching:

```
oid: "object5"
```

Out of each document array and then still be able to **fall back** to the first element of the array in a query

So I'm looking for some **strong** `fu` to be able to return the results.

And the **solution** cannot be to add another field in the main document referencing the value of the **default** field in the array document. Not having this is actually the point so the `$pull` operation works in a [**multi**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/modify-documents/) document update mode.

**EDIT**

This is intended as a query and I really mean when the **default** attribute is not set I want the first element in the array as it is listed. Every time.

The strings are sample data so don't rely on lexical order. All `object#` references are likely real **$oid** in the real world.

This may end up as a bounty. Schema changes are accepted within the tolerance of the update as mentioned. At worst the findings are a reasonable basis for a JIRA issue.

For reference, I launched this based out of thinking from my answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521728/how-do-i-implement-this-mongodb-query-update-operation-csharp-driver/21524313#21524313), which is largely about re-thinking the schema to accommodate the goal.

Good hunting.

P.S And [Webscale](http://www.mongodb-is-web-scale.com/), people. Updates on the collection need to happen without iteration as there could be a really, really, ( oh webscale! ) big number of them.

Comment: To be clear, does each "Book" represent a document in the collection (i.e. these are multiple documents with arrays, not a single document with multiple arrays)?

Comment: @Stennie Absolutely. Think of this collection as a set of documents with each document having a field that contains a sub-document array

Comment: It can be done using two find() queries. Will that be ok?

Comment: @cj0809 Looking for fully clarified answers here. The ideal case is a single query over the wire. It's kind of too easy to get a result set and iterate. If you believe you have an answer then post it

Comment: @NeilLunn Good question :) Made me to think for a while

Comment: As an alternative to aggregating you could consider pushing to [sorted arrays](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) so the default field is always first, or explicitly add a `default:true` to the first element in arrays without a default (which could be done with a multi-update). If you know the default is always the first array element you then have the option of using the [`$pop` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pop/) to remove it.

Comment: It seems that the order of the documents is preserved in the $unwind and the $sort on the "refs.default" will only re-position the document with that value per _id. So the answers seem to apply no matter what the data. Could not get a result where the order was changed from the original otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example using the Aggregation Framework in MongoDB 2.4.9 that I think achieves the result you are after:

```
db.books.aggregate(

    // Unwind the refs array
    { $unwind: "$refs" },

    // Sort by refs.default descending so "true" values will be first, nulls last
    { $sort: {
        "refs.default" : -1
    }},

    // Group and take the first ref; should either be "default:true" or first element
    { $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        name: { $addToSet: "$name" },
        refs: { $first: "$refs" }
    }},

    // (optional) Sort by name to match the example output
    { $sort: {
        name: 1,
    }},

    // (optional) Clean up output
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        name: 1,
        refs: 1
    }}
)
```

Sample result:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "name" : [
                "Book1"
            ],
            "refs" : {
                "oid" : "object5",
                "default" : true
            }
        },
        {
            "name" : [
                "Book2"
            ],
            "refs" : {
                "oid" : "object5",
                "default" : true
            }
        },
        {
            "name" : [
                "Book3"
            ],
            "refs" : {
                "oid" : "object4"
            }
        },
        {
            "name" : [
                "Book4"
            ],
            "refs" : {
                "oid" : "object4",
                "default" : true
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Notes:

- This makes an assumption on the sort order behaviour for `refs` where "default:true" is missing. On brief testing the original order appears to be preserved, so the "first" element of the array is as expected.
- Due to the aggregation operators used, the output `name` is a single element array, and `refs` becomes an embedded object. Rather than manipulating further in the Aggregation Framework, you could just reference the correct fields in your application code.

Comment: Nice docs. The consideration I am trying to keep in mind is preserving the order of the array, so what is first is always the result when it is not **flagged** as default. Sorts and $first after unwind worry me that they will not return the same result every time.

Comment: I think as long as you are only using two values for the `refs.default` field (`true` or null) the order should work. If you add `false` to the mix, both current answers are going to be unreliable because the sort order will be: true, false, null. Similarly, you might want to test with arrays that have multiple `default:true` fields. I think what you ideally want is an array index expression in aggregation that can be used in `$project` and `$cond`. I suggest upvoting/watching [SERVER-4589](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4589) in the MongoDB issue tracker.

Comment: Ah yes the issue does have all the traits. It seems to be the thing to implement, to be absolutely sure that is. I often specify that internal workings of API should not be expected to **always** work as implemented unless it is specifically documented so. Refactoring happens, as we say.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following aggregate query will work,

```
db.books.aggregate(
    {$unwind:'$refs'},
    {$group:{_id:{name:'$name',def:'$refs.default'},refs:{$first:'$refs'}}},
    {$sort:{'_id.def':-1}},
    {$group:{_id:'$_id.name',refs:{$first:'$refs'}}},
    {$project:{name:'$_id',refs:1,_id:0}}
)
```

Result:

```
{
    "result" : [
            {
                    "refs" : {
                            "oid" : "object4"
                    },
                    "name" : "Book3"
            },
            {
                    "refs" : {
                            "oid" : "object5",
                            "default" : true
                    },
                    "name" : "Book1"
            },
            {
                    "refs" : {
                            "oid" : "object5",
                            "default" : true
                    },
                    "name" : "Book2"
            },
            {
                    "refs" : {
                            "oid" : "object4",
                            "default" : true
                    },
                    "name" : "Book4"
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
```

}

Comment: I think the catch here is in the use of **$first**. Part of the problem is that the original array is **ordered** as you would expect an array to be. Thus I would be expecting the original order to be honored. Nice go at this though and much in line with my first thoughts

Comment: @NeilLunn: The documents are grouped in the same order they are unwound, so I think `$first` should be order preserving in this case. This works out equivalent to the pipeline I have with a few extra steps because of the second group (however, the `name` field doesn't end up an array :).

Comment: @Stennie I'm cool with that if you absolutely say so. But it is not what is said in the docs for [**$first**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/)

Comment: I think the caveat is that this is unwinding arrays followed by a `$first`, but could be mistaken here (would have to peek at the code). If you just had a stream of documents and took the `$first` element the order is definitely unpredictable (may vary based on document order).